# Ionic blank project's build failed after adding mfp-push plugin

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

create an blank ionic project and added mfp and mfp-push plugins. Tried to build and got this error:
BUILD FAILED in 41s
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\saikmeda\TestFbSdk\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibm\mobilefirstplatform\clientsdk\cordovaplugins\push\CDVMFPPush.java:100: error: cannot access FirebaseInstanceIdService
                MFPPush.getInstance().initialize(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), timeout);
                       ^
  class file for com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService not found
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s

Answer (score 1):

The latest MFP 8.0 client side iFix for Android has been modified to work with FCM completely. The error message you see is coming because there are some changes needed in your Android project - specifically around removing GCM classes and modifying for FCM.

Follow the instructions in the link to get your project working:

http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/android/#migrate-to-fcm

Now, all this is required only if you use MFP's push feature. If you do not , you can remove `cordova-plugin-mfp-push` plugin from your project and rebuild it.